# How can I stop a Clip from outside of the function it was started?

Tags: java

I am currently working on a small game for a class project. I thought it would be cool to add music to the game. I have a method that can play a .wav file and put it on loop (if specified).

```
public static synchronized void playSound(final String url, boolean repeat) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        // The wrapper thread is unnecessary, unless it blocks on the
        // Clip finishing; see comments.
        public void run() {
            try {
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                        Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + url));
                clip.open(inputStream);
                if (repeat == true)
                    clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
                else
                    clip.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

My question is, how can I stop the Clip outside of the function call. This method is mostly lifted off the internet with minor tweaks by  me so I understand I may need to redo the whole thing for the functionality I want. However, as the player moves between rooms, I would like the ability to stop the music that is already playing and change tracks.

Here is what I have tried:

- returning AudioSystem.getClip(). This does not work because of a "LineUnavailableException".
- returning a Clip object as a global flag so I can call stop() on it whenever necessary. However, I found Clip is actually an interface so I can not instantiate an object of Clip type.

What I would like to try but don't know how to implement:

- playSound() only operates on one DataLine. In that case, the current file would just be overwritten. I have no idea if that is how DataLines operate though.
- Any better idea than what I just said.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is an interface or class, you still can save the `clip` reference somewhere (as you said as a "global flag"). Then you call the `stop()` method when necessary.

Comment: Could you speak a little more to how I would do this? My compiler seems determined to not let me "return clip".

Comment: You cannot use `return` to return a value inside the `run()` method of the `Runnable()` interface since the return type of `run()` is `void` (and it has to keep that way). But you still can save the `Clip` reference somewhere else like a field of the class you are in. You can write something like `YourClass.musicClip = clip;` and later write `YourClass.musicClip.stop()` to stop playing the music.

Comment: That does the trick. Feels like a stupid question in hindsight. I even had all the infrastructure in place to do that. Thank you for you help.